# Twython error when trying to update twitter status with pic. Gives TypeError: update_status_with_media() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, twitter, arguments, image-uploading, twython

I am using the Twython module and am trying to upload a picture as my status on my Twitter account.

```
from twython import Twython

TWITTER_APP_KEY = '#myappkey'
TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET = '#myappkeysecret'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = '#myaccesstoken'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '#myaccesstokensecret'

t = Twython(TWITTER_APP_KEY, TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

photo = open('twitterpics/picture.jpg', 'rb')

t.update_status_with_media(status='hello!', media=photo)
```

The code above gives the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "twythonlearning.py", line 21, in <module>
    t.update_status_with_media(status='hello!', media=photo)
TypeError: update_status_with_media() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Other functions such as t.update_status(status='test') or t.get_home_timeline() work perfectly fine. I have searched online for similar problems and can't seem to find the problem with my code. I have tried capitalising the arguments 'status' and 'media' and I've also checked the size of the media file which is less than 3mb (only 75k).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works for me.

Not sure what it could be though , as all i did was copy and paste into a new file and add my keys etc in, open a local file and it worked.

Not much help sorry but maybe try just creating a new file and starting again and adding the code in there. I had a similar issue when I was messing about with Twython and I for the life of me couldn't work out what was wrong. So just reverted to a previous working version and went from there.

Only suggestion is that maybe the image is malformed and therefore it is giving you an error. Try a different image.

You should really be using this method of tweeting with an image, upload the image and then add the image id to the update_status , maybe that will work for you.

```
photo = open('twitterpics/picture.jpg', 'rb')

ids = twitter.upload_media(media=photo)

twitter.update_status(status='Checkout this cool image!', media_ids=ids['media_id'])
```

Comment: Could i get more info on this attribute as  i get an error:AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'upload_media'